# type intersection in parameter list for RequestListener

Tags: typescript

The definition of `RequestListener` in http.d.ts is

```
type RequestListener<
        Request extends typeof IncomingMessage = typeof IncomingMessage,
        Response extends typeof ServerResponse = typeof ServerResponse,
    > = (req: InstanceType<Request>, res: InstanceType<Response> & { req: InstanceType<Request> }) => void;
```

The precedence of the intersect operator (&) is unclear to me.  The right side is obviously the value in curly brackets, but what is the left side?  Only the `res` argument or both of the arguments? And given that the definition on the right is the same as the definition for `req` on the left, what is this intersection trying to accomplish?

I can't find anything in the typescript manual that defines the precedence of operators. My best guess is that the type of the second argument to `RequestListener` is either `Response` or `Request`, but I don't think that makes sense (at least for the callback for `http.CreateServer`

I'm trying to use the typescript definitions programmatically to understand the arguments and return types for node functions and in particular arguments to callbacks.

Comment: Read as `res: (InstanceType<Response> & { req: InstanceType<Request> })`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.